# How to disable all forms of local caching in KeyCloak?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

The official documentation specifies how to disable realm and user caching, but how do I disable other local caching mentioned in `infinispan` in `standalone.xml`, like `sessions`, `clientSessions` etc?

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_installation/#disabling-caching

Answer (score 1):

Disabling caching for session is not a good idea since all types of sessions stored ONLY in infinispan cache. Afaik there was an option described in documentation (or maybe a topic in Keycloak mailing list) that allows you to also persist all sessions in DB, but that was discouraged because of great performance penalty.

Comment: Can you share that mailing/doc, since I after an extensive search couldn't find it?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/keycloak-user

Comment: Can I use WildFly admin console to change the DataSource of these caches in Infinispan, to, say, KeycloakDS (which in my case in MySQL) ?